# Internal GPS interfering with mock locations?

Tags: applications, gps, geolocation

I've been using mock locations in my latest endeavors, and I'm having some issues. I enabled a mock location app from the developer options, set my Location Mode to 'Device Only,' and took precautions such as moving the app to System.

Everything is working how I intended it, except my location keeps bouncing between the mock location and my actual location. I've tried desperately to prevent my internal GPS from interfering with the mocked location, but with no luck.

The only method that I managed to have success with was by wrapping aluminum foil around my phone to inhibit the GPS.. this works but it's very inconvenient. I'd be grateful to anyone who can shine light on my troubles.

I'm running rooted Android 6.01 (Marshmallow) with a OnePlus Two device if it matters. I've tried different mock location apps with similar results on them all.

Comment: OP's follow-up question: [Disabling the GPS?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/151009/44325)