# Disabling the GPS?

Tags: gps, geolocation

Is it possible to disable the internal GPS of a device? I need to disable the hardware itself without disabling location services.

Currently I've only been able to achieve this by wrapping my phone in aluminum foil. I'd much prefer a more convenient software method.

I'm running rooted Android 6.01 (Marshmallow) on a OnePlus Two device.

Comment: OP's previous question (for additional context): [Internal GPS interfering with mock locations?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/150994/44325)

Answer (score 0):

You can set your location services to battery saver in your settings -> location -> mode.  That will leave location services on using network and wifi only.and not use gps.

Comment: I believe this defeats the purpose for me because the mock location becomes determined as my actual location in this scenario. I need to test in 'Device only' (GPS) mode without the interference I'm getting from the phones internal GPS. 

Currently my mock location is working, but it bounces between the mock and my actual location.